# Symmetric group irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, gap, computer-algebra-systems

Given a symmetric group, I'd like to get explicit matrices for the Young natural irreducible representations. (These are different from the generic unitary/orthogonal irreps; the natural
irreps are matrices with integer entries). Does anyone know how to get these in gap or any of it's
packages? (I looked at hecke package which seems relevant but I couldn't see how to use it for that).

Comment: I'm not sure if the Hecke package will compute those matrices, but Sage seems to have something: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/symmetric_group_representations.html

Comment: This is helpful; thanks. I installed the latest sage and tried what's in the link; it works fine. I tried sage a year or two ago but ended up not using much. The new version (python 3 based?) looks more polished; I'll experiment with sage some more...still I would be interested to know if it can also be done in gap.